# How to target individual div & apply class or attribute id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i select each div inside parent div & apply class (om_0 & go on) with increasing index number. Here I am unable to target each div.

Or how can I add attribute id="om_0", id="om_1", id="om_2" etc. to each div

The problem is it's applying all classes in one div & repeat it

```js
var cirLength = $("div#circleBox > div").length;
 
 for(var i=0; i<cirLength; i++){
  $("div#circleBox").find('div').addClass('om_'+i);
 }
```

```html
<div id="circleBox"><div class="om_0 om_1 om_2"><span>AcessGreen</span></div><div  class="om_0 om_1 om_2"><span>AccessBlue</span></div><div class="om_0 om_1 om_2"><span>AccessOrange</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** to iterate jQuery objects

```js
$("div#circleBox").find('div').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass('om_' + i);
  // If you need to add it as id then use `this.id= 'om_' + i ` instead of `$(this).addClass('om_' + i)`
});
```

```css
.om_0 {
  color: red;
}
.om_1 {
  color: green;
}
.om_2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circleBox">
  <div><span>AcessGreen</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>AccessBlue</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>AccessOrange</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

With your own code you need to select individual item using **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**

```js
var cirLength = $("div#circleBox > div").length;

for (var i = 0; i < cirLength; i++) {
  $("div#circleBox").find('div').eq(i).addClass('om_' + i);
}
```

```css
.om_0 {
  color: red;
}
.om_1 {
  color: green;
}
.om_2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circleBox">
  <div><span>AcessGreen</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>AccessBlue</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>AccessOrange</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Pranav - Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @amolD glad to help :)